Force plate or gauge to measure timed static contractions
I have incorporated timed static contractions (TSC) - a kind of advanced isometrics Ken Hutchin developed out of his Super Slow training protocol - into my training.
I have a power rack on which I can adjust the height of a bar and make it immovable for a given exercise.
As a simple description, Hutchin's TSC trains each exercise for 90 seconds, working up in 30 second increments from moderate, to intense, to all out.
I stand for all the exercises doing one set of each:

Dead lift
Squat
High pull
Overhead press
Shoulder shrug

At my age (72) I have as much focus on skeletal load as building/maintaining strength.
This protocol faces the challenge that pushing or pulling of a fixed bar only gives you a subjective idea of the force you've applied.
I'd like to refine and measure this sort of training.
Does some type of force gauge or plate exist that could give me feed back on the force I exert through the 90 seconds of each exercise?
I'd imagine something like a scale (maybe a bit larger) that I could stand on while I pull, push, or press the bar that could give me a readily viewable digital output.
I've thought about using something like a Withings scale, but I doubt that they'd hold up to the kind a forces one would generate for very long.
Thoughts appreciated.

I found what looks like a reasonable and cost effective solution, a Digital livestock scale with 300kg capacity.
Not certain it will do everything I'd like, but seems like a good place to start.

